# Avoid RelativeLAyout text overlapping on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a this problem and I don't know what to do, I tried putting the text in linear layout but it was usaless.
I'm posting an image about the issue too. I don't know what else to write to remove stackoverflow's alert: "your message is mostly code etc..."

[image: Sample of the issue in the red circle]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="true"

    >

   <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     >


         >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.92"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"

        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"

        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" >

    </TextView>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name" />

     </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use Weight !! like 10/80/10 (it can work like percents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this.... And I hope this will help you..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:clipToPadding="true"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingLeft="8dp"
 android:paddingRight="8dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:alpha="0.92"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Fixed but using `<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name" />`

Comment: Still having one problem: imageview is not vertically centered

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout.LayoutParameters xml parameter [layout_toLeftOf](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_toLeftOf)

```
<TextView
     [...]
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"/>
```

Bonus tip, if the text does not fit you might want to check out TextView [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The text inside the textview will crop depending on the length of the text. If the text length is more than what textview should hold, then it will crop. To avoid this cropping, you could set the width of the textview to be more than the text length. You can also decrease the font size of the text.

Alternatively you can use ellipses:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```